# How to save to a remote server with Django

Tags: django, postgresql, remote-access, pythonanywhere

I'm fairly new to Python and Django. I've recently got a Django app working on localhost in Linux Mint 18.3 with a Postgresql database.

I've uploaded the app to PythonAnywhere, but unfortunately it requires Java for some of the NLP features (Stanford POS). Is there a way to parse and process the data on a local system and save it to the remote Postgres DB and serving the data from the remote server?

I've looked at some answers on here regarding SSH tunnelling, but I'm not sure this applies here? Alternatively would it be possible to save to the local database and periodically migrate the data to the remote database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes -- to access your PythonAnywhere Postgres DB from your local machine, you'll need to use SSH tunnelling.   If you're using a Unix-like operating system (eg. Linux or Mac) on your local machine, the "Manual SSH tunnelling" instructions at the bottom of [this help page](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/AccessingMySQLFromOutsidePythonAnywhere) will handle that, with a couple of tweaks.

The SSH command on the help page is:

```
ssh -L 3306:username.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com:3306 username@ssh.pythonanywhere.com
```

...which, as you can see, is for MySQL.  To make it work for your PythonAnywhere Postgres server, replace:

- The first `3306` with `5432` (which means that on your local machine, it will use the default Postgres port)
- The `username.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com` with the Postgres server hostname from the "Postgres" tab on the "Databases" page inside PythonAnywhere.
- The second `3306` with the port from the "Postgres" tab on the "Databases" page inside PythonAnywhere.

So you'll wind up with something like

```
ssh -L 5432:username-123.postgres.pythonanywhere-services.com:10123 username@ssh.pythonanywhere.com
```

...with different values for `username`, `123` and and `10123`.

When you run that command (and entered your PythonAnywhere login password, which it will prompt you for), a process will start up on your machine that looks like a Postgres server to all local processes, but is actually just forwarding everything back and forth to the PythonAnywhere-hosted database server.   So you can run your parsing and processing code locally, and it will work transparently.

Comment: This seems to connect the terminal to the PythonAnywhere localhost, but when I use a separate terminal to then execute the parsing script, I get the following error:

    `conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
 Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?'`

Comment: Could you take a screenshot of the terminal where you're running the SSH command, just after it's connected, and post a link to it here (removing any secret stuff, of course)?

Comment: please see the image at the following link: http://imgur.com/a/EJQqW. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: OK, so that all looks OK.  What do you get if you run (on your local machine) the command `lsof | grep LISTEN | grep 5432`

Comment: It's ok, I just got it working. Looks like I just need to close and open a new terminal, not use one that was already open prior to opening the SSH tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you just have to connect your local env to your remote DB using Django `DATABASES` settings https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

Be careful to use your Django version in the doc (here 2.0)

That way you can write from your local env, and read from your remote server (using the same settings to connect to your remote DB)

Comment: I tried this previously but this would not allow access from my local app.

Comment: Where is hosted your DB ?

Comment: http://www.pythonanywhere.com. Giles who has also supplied an answer is one of the support team there.