# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yoursite'

Tags: python, django

I'm relatively new to both Python and Django, and I've had an app developed by someone else. I'm trying to write a script which automatically opens an SSH Tunnel and runs a command from my local machine to my remote postgres database so that I can do a parse locally - this is normally done from the terminal by typing `python manage.py parse`. This has worked previously when I have [run a manual SSH tunnel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49100598/how-to-save-to-a-remote-server-with-django) but now want to set it up to run in a script and close the connection automatically. My script is currently set as below:

```
import psycopg2
import sshtunnel
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

sshtunnel.SSH_TIMEOUT = 5.0
sshtunnel.TUNNEL_TIMEOUT = 5.0

with sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('ssh.pythonanywhere.com'),
    ssh_username='ssh_username', ssh_password='ssh_password',
    remote_bind_address=('username2.postgres.pythonanywhere-services.com', port)
) as tunnel:
    params = {
        "dbname": 'dbname',
        "user": 'user',
        "password": 'password',
        "host": 'host',
        "port": tunnel.local_bind_port,
    }

    connection = psycopg2.connect(**params)
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    execute_from_command_line(["manage.py", "parse"])

    cursor.close
    connection.close()
```

I'm now getting the error below when I run the script (which is located in the root file of my app):

```
/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
  """)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ssh_tunnel.py", line 24, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(["manage.py", "parse"])
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 307, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 110, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yoursite'
```

It seems to me that it must be an issue where I haven't changed the name of a script somewhere, but having done a search through my system I can't seem to find 'yoursite' in any of my code. Does anyone have any idea where the code might be that this error is referring to?

Settings.py contents:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'api',
    'taggit',
    'rest_framework',
    'taggit_serializer',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter',
    'corsheaders',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'api.context_processors.menubar'
                # 'social_django.context_processors.backends',
                # 'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
DATABASES = {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'username',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
    }
}

    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'HOST': 'xxxxxxxx',
            'NAME': 'name',
            'USER': 'user',
            'PASSWORD': 'password',
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES['default']['HOST'] = '127.0.0.1'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (

    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'api.permissions.POSTOnlyAuthentication',
    ),
}

SESSION_SERIALIZER = "django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer"

SITE_ID = 1

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'api.MyUser'


EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'app@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'app.development'
EMAIL_PORT = 587

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'optional'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
LOGIN_URL = LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'api/auth/login/'
ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET = True

ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_ANONYMOUS_REDIRECT_URL = LOGIN_URL
```

Authorisation details have been changed.

Structure is:

```
App Root
-requirements.txt
-app.yaml
-manage.py
-ssh_tunnel.py
api
mysite
-__init__.py
-settings.py
-wsgi.py
static
```

Comment: Please provide your settings file and the whole directory structure.

Comment: I have added this information @NihalSharma

Comment: Where is the script located? Can you please provide the script also?

Comment: The script is in the app root, as mentioned. It is called ssh_tunnel.py and is already provided.